# Составной запрос

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы, в одной есть список пользователей, а в другой есть список их заказов.

Можно ли получить все данные пользователя из первой таблицы, а из второй запросить SUM по id всех его заказов, всего одним запросом?

```
SELECT * , SUM(transactions.sum) AS Avg_price FROM users, transactions
WHERE users.type = 'agent' AND transactions.user_id = users.id
```

Вот такой запрос выдает то, что мне нужно. Но если нет заказов в transactions, то он не покажет пользователя. Как исправить? –

Comment: лучше добавьте в тело самого вопроса, а не как комментарий

Answer (score 2):

Можно.
Для этого надо выучить базовые операторы языка SQL.

Объединяет таблицы оператор `JOIN`.
Группирует записи - `GROUP BY`
Суммирует данные в колонке функция `SUM()`

Для того, чтобы из левой таблицы выводились все записи, а не только те, для которых есть соответствие в правой, надо использовать `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: обновил шапку запросом